# cdkDragHandle doesn't work inside child component

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

Using @angular/cdk 7.2.1: If defining a parent component holding a cdkDropList and a nested list of cdkDrag components, defining a cdkDragHandle inside the nested child component doesn't work. If the same structure is all in the same component, cdkDragHandle works perfectly.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfvmuj?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.html

Has anyone found a fix to get cdkDragHandle to work even when not defined in the same component as cdkDrag?

Comment: Found the issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13784

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

Parent Component:

```
<div cdkDropList #list="cdkDropList"
  [cdkDropListData]="myArray"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">

  <app-item
    *ngFor="let item of myArray"
    cdkDrag>
    <div cdkDragHandle></div>
  </app-item>

</div>
```

Child Component (app-item):

```
<div class="drag-container">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="drag-handle">drag here</div>
</div>
```

Then style the cdk-drag-handle class in the parent component. cdk-drag-handle comes with material, so we do not need to apply it manually:

```
.cdk-drag-handle {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 100;
   background-color: transparent;
   cursor: move;
 }
```

Then style the drag-container with position: relative and whatever you want. I have an item inside it (drag-handle) which also takes the full width and height of the container, that contains an image (just as a sidenote).

Comment: Thank you, lajuma, for the proposed solution. This is basically what is suggested by others in the referenced issue link above, github.com/angular/material2/issues/13784.

Comment: Great solution! You just introduced me to <ng-content> tag. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:
Instead of using cdkDragHandle, just stop mouse down event propagation as bellow.
Then only header can be dragged.

```html
<div>
  <header></header>
  <body (mousedown)="$event.stopPropagation()"></body>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure when this was added , setting `cdkDragRootElement` in the child worked for me.

In the child component `<div cdkDrag cdkDragRootElement="app-bot-prompt-selector">` `app-bot-prompt-selector` is the parent element that needs to be drag able

https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDrag

Answer (score 0):

Because `CdkDrag` use `@ContentChildren` to catch all `CdkDragHandle`s, so you have to define all `CdkDragHandle`s as *content children* **BUT** there is another solution if you don't want to define `cdkDragHandle` as descendants content children, you can add `cdkDragHandle` to `cdkDrag` manually:

```
@Component({
  selector: "child-component",
  template: `
    <div cdkDragHandle>handle</div>
  `
)}
export class ChildComponent {

  @ViewChild(CdkDragHandle, { static: true }) handle: CdkDragHandle;

  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(CDK_DRAG_PARENT) public cdk) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cdk._handles.length = 1;
    this.cdk._handles._results = [this.handle];
    this.cdk._handles.changes.next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found to this problem is to add the drag handle as a content but not the main one, because I needed that for other components.

```
  
<div cdkDropListGroup>
<div 
#mainContainerList="cdkDropList" 
cdkDropList 
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"  
[cdkDropListData]="this.dataModel.model.items"

class="page-builder-content">
    <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let component of  this.dataModel.model.items;let i=index">
           
        
       <app-component-selector >
<--- Here -->
       <span dragHandle cdkDragHandle class="material-icons">
        open_with
        </span>
<--- Here -->
<div >
other data for view
</div>
</app-component-selector>
```

then in the sub child component I use this dragHandle where I need it

```
   <div class="col-2">
        <ng-content select="[dragHandle]">

        </ng-content>
       </div>
<ng-content></ng-content><-- Other data-->
```